# A div has two class name but Why do i have to use both class names to change the style of the <div>?

Tags: html, css

So i have two products in my html with the first class name "product" second product class name of "product" and "image-reverse". With in the product class i have an image and and some text, with class name "product-1-image", "product-2-image", "product-2-info" and "product-2-info". I know i should be using id instead of class for unique styles but because i am just experimenting things, so it is fine for now.

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-1-image">
    <img src="img/precision-clean.png">
  </div>
  <div class="product-1-info">
    <h2>PRECISION CLEAN</h2>
    <p>Features cup-shaped bristles to reach deep between teeth, for cleaner teeth and healthier gums* </p>
    <p>*vs a regular manual toothbrush</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product image-reverse">
  <div class="product-2-image">
    <img src="img/floss-action.png">
  </div>
  <div class="product-2-info">
    <h2>FLOSSACTION</h2>
    <p>Features soft MicroPulseTM bristles for deep cleaning between teeth.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the style applied to both products is as following

```
.product {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 object-fit: contain;
}

.product-1-image {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.product-1-info {
 max-width: 500px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.product-2-image {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.product-2-info {
 max-width: 500px;
}

.image-reverse {
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

now i have added an extra style when the browser size decreases.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.product {
 flex-direction: column;
}

.product.image-reverse {
 flex-direction: column;
}


.product-1-image,
.product-1-info {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-2-image,
.product-2-info {
  width: 100%;
}

}
```

Why is it that in @media style i have to mention .product and .image-reverse class to change the flex-direction to column, where as in the normal style i could just use .image-reverse class to flex-direction to row-reverse?

I have tried to just use one class name as bellow but it does not work. why?

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.image-reverse {
  flex-direction:column;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the specificity applied to `flex-direction`.

Initially, when you set `flex-direction: row-reverse` outside media query, its specificity was '0-1-0' as you selected it by class name.

To override any style, you must provide styling with greater specificity than the already applied style's specificity.

In your example, when you tried to change `flex-direction` style property in the media query by just `.image-reverse` class, its specificity was still '0-1-0'.
But, when you tried with `.product.image-reverse` its specificity got summed up to '0-2-0', so that overrides the `flex-direction`.

You can read more about **specificity** and it's rules - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)